# Can PHP "file_get_contents()" function read a file while it's being written?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, flock, file-put-contents

How does PHP "file_get_contents()" function handles the request if a given file is being written? Does it wait until the writing process is finished and then read the file, or, does it just fail to read the file?

Does "file_get_contents()" function use "flock()" function by default?

Comment: Depends on the sharing level, when the file is opened. Many text editors will recognize when the currently displayed file is changed by another process. So, yes, it's actually possible to write and read at the same time (though not entirely simultaneously, obviously)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz, from User1010 and my test codes, it seems that "file_get_contents()" returns empty string if a given file is being written, so I wrote "flock_file_get_contents()" function as an alternative (Better solutions are always welcome)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests and, indeed, "file_get_contents()" does not make use of "flock()" and there is no way to use "LOCK_SH" flag as an alternative!

If a file is being written, "file_get_contents()" does not wait in queue, it reads the file then it returns an empty string!

I wrote "flock_file_get_contents()" function as an alternative, if a file is being written, it waits in queue until the write process is over then it reads the file!

Better solutions are always welcome!

[OBS]:

- The only thing I don't like about "flock()" is the fact that it does not handle the requests in order of call!

[Edited]:

- ["wait_Read_Write_end_of($File)" Functions (Alternative)](https://straighttips.blogspot.com/2020/11/php-wait-read-write-end-of-file.html)
- "flock_file_put_contents()" function (Added)
- "flock_file_get_contents()" function uses "LOCK_SH" instead "LOCK_EX" flag!

[image]

```
<?php

$Overwrite_Sleep = 10;       //seconds
$flock_GFC_Sleep = 2;       //seconds

$File = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php') . ".txt";

if (isset($_POST["Request"])){

    if($_POST["Request"] == "Get_File_Content"){echo file_get_contents($File);
    }else if ($_POST["Request"] == "flock_Get_File_Content"){echo flock_file_get_contents($File);
    }else{

        flock_file_put_contents($File, function($F_P){

        $File_Content = file_get_contents($F_P);
        $File_Content = str_replace("O", "A", $File_Content);
        $File_Content = str_replace("p", "t", $File_Content);
        $File_Content = str_replace("0", "", $File_Content);

            //the below is basically what "file_put_contents()" does, except the "sleep()" part
 
        $File_Handle = fopen($F_P, 'w');

        fwrite($File_Handle, $File_Content . sleep($GLOBALS["Overwrite_Sleep"]));       //the write process takes some time to finish
            
        fclose($File_Handle);

        }, $Return_Message);

    echo ($Return_Message == 1) ? "File Overwritten" : "Failed: " . $Return_Message;
    }

return;
}

file_put_contents($File, "Oops");

function flock_file_get_contents($File){     //______________________________________________

    $File_Handle = fopen("$File", "r");
    if(flock($File_Handle, LOCK_SH)){       //on success, this script execution waits here until older scripts in queue unlock the file

    $File_Content = file_get_contents($File);

    sleep($GLOBALS["flock_GFC_Sleep"]);

    flock($File_Handle, LOCK_UN);       //unlock the file so new scripts in queue can continue execution

    }else{$File_Content = ["flock"=>"Fail"];}
    fclose($File_Handle);

return $File_Content;
}

function flock_file_put_contents($File, $Do_This, &$Return_Var = ""){      //__________________________________________

        $File_Handle = fopen($File, 'r');
        if (flock($File_Handle, LOCK_EX)) {     //on success, this script execution waits here until older scripts in queue unlock the file
 
        $Do_This($File);

        $Return_Message = 1;

        flock($File_Handle, LOCK_UN);       //unlock the file so new scripts in queue can continue execution

        }else{$Return_Message = "flock() Failed";}
        fclose($File_Handle);

$Return_Var = $Return_Message;

return $Return_Message;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<div style="  float:left;">
<input type="button" value="Overwrite File (Wait <?php echo $Overwrite_Sleep ?> Seconds)"  onclick='Test("Overwrite_File", this, Call_Count++)'>
<br>
<div id="Response_Overwrite"></div>
</div>

<div style="  float:left; margin-left: 50px; ">
<input type="button" value="file_get_contents()"  onclick='Test("Get_File_Content", this, Call_Count++)'>
<br>
<div id="Response_Get_Content"></div>
</div>

<div style="  float:left; margin-left: 50px; ">
<input type="button" value="flock_file_get_contents() - Wait <?php echo $flock_GFC_Sleep ?> seconds"  onclick='Test("flock_Get_File_Content", this, Call_Count++)'>
<br>
<div id="Response_flock_Get_Content"></div>
</div>

<br style=" clear: both;"><br><br>

<?php
echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . "<br><br>";
echo __FILE__ . "<br><br>"; 

echo basename(__FILE__) . "<br><br>"; 
echo basename(__FILE__, '.php') . "<br><br>";

echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . "<br><br>"; 
echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], '.php') . "<br><br>";
?>


<script>

Call_Count = 1;

function Test(Option, El, Call_Count){      //____________________________

    //El.disabled = true;

    //if (Option === "Overwrite_File"){document.getElementById("Response_Overwrite").innerHTML += "(Please Wait <?php echo $Overwrite_Sleep ?> Seconds) ";
    //}else if (Option === "flock_Get_File_Content"){document.getElementById("Response_flock_Get_Content").innerHTML += 'File Content is: ';
    //}else{document.getElementById("Response_Get_Content").innerHTML += 'File Content is: '}

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', "");      //blank url (send to same page)

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     //necessary to send "Request" POST key below to php

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4) {     //"4", request finished and response is ready!

            if (Option === "Overwrite_File"){document.getElementById("Response_Overwrite").innerHTML += this.responseText + " (Call " + Call_Count + ")<br>";
            }else if (Option === "flock_Get_File_Content"){
            document.getElementById("Response_flock_Get_Content").innerHTML += '"' + this.responseText + '" (Call ' + Call_Count + ')<br>';
            }else{document.getElementById("Response_Get_Content").innerHTML += '"' + this.responseText + '" (Call ' + Call_Count + ')<br>';}

        El.disabled = false;
        }
    };

http.send('Request=' + Option);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the time a file is being written it will return nothing,

```py
import time

with open('output.file', 'wb') as file:
    for x in range(30):
        file.write(b'Test')

        time.sleep(1)
```

```php
<?php
    var_dump(file_get_contents('output.file'));
```

Output `string(0) ""` (Whist open)
Output `string(120) "TestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest"` Once written

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I did my own tests, and yes, it seems that "file_get_contents()" returns empty string while files are being written, unfortunately! I wrote "flock_file_get_contents()" function as an alternative, but if there area better solutions, please share them here!